# Dynamic Horizontal scrollable table view header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 4 different scenarios as below. When user click the table view cell server is called and previous state is shown in header in same class as below. I have place dynamic horizontal scroll for long text.

[image]

[image]

I have implemented following code

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 40)];

    UIButton *BtnBreadcrumb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [BtnBreadcrumb addTarget:self action:@selector(selectBtnBreadcrumb:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [BtnBreadcrumb setTitle:[self.subCategoryDict objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    BtnBreadcrumb.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    BtnBreadcrumb.tintColor=TextColor;
    CGSize stringsize = [[self.subCategoryDict objectForKey:@"name"] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]}];
    BtnBreadcrumb.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, stringsize.width, 40);
    [contentView addSubview:BtnBreadcrumb];

    CGSize labelSize;
    if (!ArayBreadcrumb || !ArayBreadcrumb.count){
    }else{

        NSMutableString* BreadcrumbName = [NSMutableString new];
        int expression=(int)[ArayBreadcrumb count];
        for(int i = 0; i < expression; i ++)
        {
            [BreadcrumbName appendFormat:@"/ %@", [ArayBreadcrumb objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        //CGSize
        labelSize = [BreadcrumbName sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]}];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(stringsize.width+10, 5, labelSize.width, 40)];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
        label.textColor = ThemeColor;
        [label setText:BreadcrumbName];
        [contentView addSubview:label];
     }

    [contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.933f green:0.933f blue:0.933f alpha:1.00f]];

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 40)];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(stringsize.width+10+ labelSize.width,scroll.frame.size.height);
   // scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 40);
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    [scroll addSubview:contentView];

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    return scroll;

}


-(void) selectBtnBreadcrumb:(id)sender{
  //  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

It is working fine. Now I have to implement that when user clicks the `BtnBreadcrumb` data in  `NSMutableString* BreadcrumbName` need to be deleted one by one in the same order as it was added and when it becomes nill only  `popViewControllerAnimated:YES` need to be called

Comment: Use 'for'-statement and `NSMutableString` instead.

Comment: @Astoria thanks for the idea of NSMutableString can u check the edited questions

Answer (score 1):

Something like a simple for loop and a mutable string would do.

#### Addition

```
NSMutableString* breadCrumbName = [NSMutableString new];
int expression=(int)[ArayBreadcrumb count];
    for(int i = 0; i < expression; i ++)
    {
        [breadCrumbName appendFormat:@"/ %@", [ArayBreadcrumb objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

#### Deletion

```
NSMutableArray *components = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];
[components removeLastObject];
str = [[components componentsJoinedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];
```

**Note:** The last item in components will be empty. And there are better ways to do this, but this is quick and dirty.

Comment: thanks for the idea of NSMutableString its working fine can u check the edited questions and give me some ideas. i have upvoted as a reward for ur help and good answer

Comment: addition code are perfect but deletion code a bit messed up dude

Comment: can u give me some ideas dude

Comment: do u have any ideas ab this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158404/how-to-add-check-box-in-custom-table-view-cell