# How to Add Check Box in custom Table View Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tags

I want to create custom check box in my Custom UITableViewCell. I have used following way in   `UITableViewCell` but doesn't find it appropriate. I need to it inside from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

 }

- (IBAction)ActionBtnSelect:(id)sender {

    if ([[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] isEqual:BtnCheckBox.currentImage] || [[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckbox.png"] isEqual:BtnCheckBox.currentImage]) {
        // do something


        if (!bool_Select) {

            [BtnCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            bool_Select =YES;

        }
        else  if (bool_Select) {
            //NSLog(@"check box untick");

            [BtnCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            bool_Select =NO;

        }

    }else{

        if (!bool_Select) {

            [BtnCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            bool_Select =YES;

        }
        else  if (bool_Select) {
            //NSLog(@"check box untick");

            [BtnCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            bool_Select =NO;

        }



    }
}
```

[image]

**I want to do it as below** using Tag

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{---------------------------------

cell.BtnCheckBox.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.BtnCheckBox addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionSingleSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

-(void)ActionSingleSelect:(UIButton*)button
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];

cell.btn.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionSingleSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```